# Find Limit via l’Hôpital’s

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

The problem is finding this limit: $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{2^x}{3^{x^2}}$ using l’Hôpital’s Rule.

Comment: Please revise the language of the problem and check the variable you used. $n=x$?

Comment: $3^x^2$ will grow much faster than $2^x$

Comment: Why on earth would one use LHR to evaluate this limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the standard log tricks
$$\log L=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\log\frac{2^x}{3^{x^2}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}x\log2-x^2\log3\\\
=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}x(\log2-x\log3)\rightarrow +\infty*-\infty=-\infty$$
Your limit is then $e^{\log L}=e^{-\infty}=0$